# Why function calling is not working while passing array as argument?

Tags: c

## Here is my code

I am trying to create an array using a function named createArray and saving the returned value in an array inside main function now when I call another function named multiplication using those array names as arguments it does not call that function and it does not also give any error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int createArray(int size)
{
    int arr[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter value of position row %d , column %d: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
int multiplication(int arr1[10][10], int arr2[10][10], int size)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    int arr3[size][size];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < size; k++)
            {
                arr3[i][j] += arr1[i][k] * arr2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("hello");
    return arr3;
}
void display(int arr[10][10], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            printf("%d \t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    printf("Enter size of the matrix:  ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int arr1, arr2, arr3;
    arr1=createArray(size);
        arr2= createArray(size);
    arr3= multiplication(arr1, arr2, size);
    // display(arr3, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            printf("%d \t", arr3[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know if there is any issue with address or pointers since array name is a pointer of first index of the array.

Comment: `return arr;` the return type of function is int, `int createArray(int size)` instead it should be `int *createArray(int size)`. The declarations `int arr1, arr2, arr3;` also should be of type `int *`

Comment: But you must not return the address of a local variable.  Please use `malloc` instead of VLA. When you `return` from `createArray` the `arr[][]` will cease to exist.

Comment: ...or, create the VLA in `main()` and pass it to `createArray()` to be have values assigned.

Comment: Welcome to C. If you know any other programming languages, it's helpful to realize, that C arrays (and strings) are something _much_ more primitive than what non-C programmer thinks arrays and strings are. 
It's only slight hyperbole to say "C has no arrays", because it's all pointers when you really _do_ anything with arrays (even `[]` really operate on a pointer). If you are learning programming with C, once you learn some other language, remember this too.

Comment: "and it does not also give any error." If you get any error, include it in your question. Or even better read and try to understand the compiler message. It should help you to find the error, what is faster than writing a question. If you can solve it, you're welcome to share the problem an ask.

Answer (score 0):

In C when you define a variable in a function, the memory is allocated on the stack, once the function returns, this memory is freed and likely overwritten by the calling the next function.

You should allocate the memory by `malloc()` or a similar mechanism and you should return a pointer.

The type `int[]` is in fact a pointer to an integer. Your `createArray()` function returns an integer, so I think it will try to return the pointer value converted to an integer and I am curious if your compiler gives any warnings about any of those issues.

I believe `int[][]` is equal to `int**`, so you should in fact allocate each row as explained for example here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/ .

Also remember that the memory will stay allocated until you free it or until the program ends, so you should make sure that you pair every `malloc()` call with a `free()` call once you do not need the data anymore.

---

I agree that "equal" is imprecise here, because I mostly meant how the pointer is stored in memory, I ignored things like how the data is stored in memory.

Comment: Re “I believe `int[][]` is equal to `**int`”: No, not at all. An `int [m][n]` has m•n `int` laid out in memory consecutively. There is no `**int`, but an `int **` is a pointer to several pointers laid out in memory consecutively, and each of those pointers may point to other memory, and those other portions of memory might or might not be laid out consecutively. This type of two-dimensional array implementation has performance issues and should not be used ordinarily.

Comment: Re “The type int[] is in fact a pointer to an integer”: The type `int []` is an array of unknown size. When a function parameter is declared to be this type, it is automatically adjusted to be an `int *`. That does not make the types the same; `int []` is not in fact `int *`. Also, `int *` is a pointer to an `int`. `int` is an integer type, but saying `int *` is a pointer to an integer is at best imprecise, since there are other integer types.

Comment: Re “In C when you define a variable in a function, the memory is allocated on the stack, once the function returns, this memory is freed and likely overwritten by the calling the next function”: This is common in C implementations but is not required by the C standard and is not universal. It is preferable to discuss object lifetimes in the terms defined by the C standard, including automatic storage duration, static storage duration, thread storage duration, and allocated storage duration.

Comment: Well, @EricPostpischil, thanks for the clarifications. I am happy to read your answer once there is one available. I am just a regular programmer, who did most of his work in C 20 years ago in MS DOS. So yes, my answer sucks, and I am ok with that. Keep doing your job, precision matters and your contributions add lots of value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `createArray` you are creating an array with automatic storage duration with `int arr[size][size];`. This means that it lives for the lifetime of the block in which it is declared. The pointer that the function's caller obtains from `return arr;` will reference an object whose lifetime is over and therefore be a dangling pointer.

To allocate an array in a function and return the array from it you have to do so dynamically using `malloc`. That way it will have allocated storage duration and live as long until `free` is called on it.

```c
// allocate array
int *arr = malloc(size_of_array * sizeof(int));
// ...
// free array after using it
free(arr);
```

Furthermore the function signature of `int createArray(int size)` currently specifies a return type of `int`. Since you actually want to return a pointer to the first entry of the array `createArray` should return `int*`.

```c
int* createArray(int size)
{
    // Reserve size * size * sizeof(int) bytes of memory.
    int *arr = malloc(size * size * sizeof(int));
    // Fill the allocated memory space
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter value of position row %d , column %d: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i * size + j]);
        }
    }
    // return a pointer to the first entry in the array
    return arr;
}
```

When declaring an array using `int arr3[size][size];` the contents of `arr3` are not specified. The same is true for dynamically allocating an array using `malloc`. You have to set each entry in `arr3` to 0, otherwise `arr3` is likely going to contain random values at the end of `multiplication`.

Your code for `multiplication` will only work properly for arrays created with `size` equal to 10 when passing `arr1` and `arr2` as `int arr1[10][10]`. It is preferrable to pass pointers to the array's first element as `int *arr1`.

As before the return type should be `int*` instead of `int`.

```c
int* multiplication(int *arr1, int *arr2, int size)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    // Reserve size * size * sizeof(int) bytes of memory for result array
    int *arr3 = malloc(size * size * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            // fill arr3 with 0
            arr3[i * size + j] = 0;
            
            // compute multiplication
            for (k = 0; k < size; k++)
            {
                arr3[i * size + j] += arr1[i * size + k] * arr2[k * size + j];
            }
        }
    }
    // return a pointer to the first entry in the result array
    return arr3;
}
```

The same modifications can be applied to `display`:

```c
void display(int *arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            printf("%d \t", arr[i * size + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

In `main` you now need to call `free` on `arr1`, `arr2` and `arr3` since they were created using `malloc`. `arr1`, `arr2` and `arr3` should also be of type `int*` instead of `int`.

```c
int main()
{
    int size;
    printf("Enter size of the matrix:  ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int *arr1, *arr2, *arr3;
    arr1 = createArray(size);
    arr2 = createArray(size);
    arr3 = multiplication(arr1, arr2, size);
    display(arr3, size);

    // free the allocated arrays
    free(arr1);
    free(arr2);
    free(arr3);
    return 0;
}
```